# Change page without reloading header/footer?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've seen a lot of sites recently that allow you to navigate to different pages (seemingly) without reloading the page. For example:

https://www.protest.eu/shop/category/men/

I know I can do it via AJAX by just replacing the content and changing the url, but that has drawbacks. Mainly, if you're trying to track page visits, they won't show up for pages that are navigated to in this way... because you're not actually visiting the page.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can just change the tracker to count on content load in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can do it via AJAX

That's how you do it.

> if you're trying to track page visits, they won't show up for pages that are navigated to in this way

How you fix that depends on what you are using to track page visits.

If, for example, you were using Google Analytics then you would do something like:

```
function ajaxLoadHandler() {
    var content = this.responseText;
    var url = "/bar.html";
    update_content_with(content);
    history.pushState({ raw_content: content }, "page 2", url);
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'pageview',
        page: url
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I figured that might be the case. Sometimes I have clients using Jetpack or Google Analytics, so I'll look into those. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This approach is called as SPA (single page application). The dowbacks you mentioned earlier can handled by some Js methods and event listener(histrory.pushstate, onpopstate... ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate.)

Some of JS framework s (like React,Backbone,CanJS,SpineJS,BatmanJS,EmberJS,AngularJS, etc) help to achive SPA sloution. These framework provides routing module to achive browser history functionality also these provides view, model, controller, collection WTC.,. You may choose one of these framework which suits for your business need.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know what the name for it was, but that's super helpful in researching now. Thanks for the info!